# Photoshop script to include nested linked smart objects

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

The original version of the below code replaced the contents of smart objects by prompting the user for a new image. I have tried amending it so that it also replaces the contents of nested smart objects.

I am not a coder and usually manage by referencing existing code and mashing different ones together and searching google for pointers. However everything I have tried still ignores the nested smart objects.

Below is one of my attempts to include nested smart objects, however the core functionality of replacing contents of smart objects is broken and it now does nothing. How could it be achieved to include nested smart objects?

```
#target photoshop

if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
    var theName = myDocument.name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
    var thePath = myDocument.path;

    // Call the function to start the replacement process
    replaceAllSmartObjectContents(myDocument);
}

function replaceAllSmartObjectContents(currentLayer) {
    if (currentLayer.typename === "ArtLayer" && currentLayer.kind === LayerKind.SMARTOBJECT) {
        // If it's a Smart Object layer, replace its contents
        replaceSmartObjectContents(currentLayer);
    } else if (currentLayer.typename === "LayerSet") {
        // If it's a layer group, recursively check its child layers
        for (var i = 0; i < currentLayer.layers.length; i++) {
            replaceAllSmartObjectContents(currentLayer.layers[i]);
        }
    }
}

function replaceSmartObjectContents(smartObjectLayer) {
    // Select the Smart Object layer
    app.activeDocument.activeLayer = smartObjectLayer;

    // Select Files
    if ($.os.search(/windows/i) != -1) {
        var theFiles = File.openDialog("Please select files", "*.psd;*.tif;*.jpg", true);
    } else {
        var theFiles = File.openDialog("Please select files", getFiles, true);
    }

    if (theFiles) {
        for (var m = 0; m < theFiles.length; m++) {
            // Replace Smart Object
            smartObjectLayer = replaceContents(theFiles[m], smartObjectLayer);
            var theNewName = theFiles[m].name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
        }
    }
}

function getFiles(theFile) {
    if (theFile.name.match(/\.(psd|tif|jpg)$/i) != null || theFile.constructor.name == "Folder") {
        return true;
    }
}

function replaceContents(newFile, theSO) {
    app.activeDocument.activeLayer = theSO;

    var idplacedLayerReplaceContents = stringIDToTypeID("placedLayerReplaceContents");
    var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    desc3.putPath(idnull, new File(newFile));
    var idPgNm = charIDToTypeID("PgNm");
    desc3.putInteger(idPgNm, 1);
    executeAction(idplacedLayerReplaceContents, desc3, DialogModes.NO);

    return app.activeDocument.activeLayer;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your requirement (1), since you need both an active layer and that layer needs to be a smart object, otherwise how would PS know which smart object to replace? Having said that, the Adobe forum has an `actions and scripting` tag for asking PS scripting questions, and is usually the first place to ask (since JavaScript 1.5, the version of JS that the legacy ActionScript that PS uses is based on, is _decades_ out of date at this point, so the odds of finding someone fluent in the PS-specific API on the Adobe forums is infinitely higher than on Stackoverflow =)

Comment: (if you do want to ask this on SO, remember that this is [not a code-writing service](/help/on-topic) so you're going to have to pick [one of those requirements](/help/how-to-ask), not all four, and then specifically talk about what code you already wrote to meet that requirement, and talk about what that did instead of what you expected, and what you already did in terms of (re)searching and debugging solutions)

Comment: noted I have edited the question

Comment: Remember to explain _how_ things break, not just "that" they break. You removed the description of what the original script does, so it's even more important to explain what it did before, what you changed (from what to what) and what that new code does (with a description of the steps you take to run it, and any errors that might result from that. Even if it "does nothing", that's behaviour you should mention in your post)

Comment: I have edited to explain "breaks" means it now "does nothing". You previously asked me to remove the 4 points so I did and edited the question to only refer to the one thing it was supposed to do and the one thing I'm tryng to add.

Comment: I didn't, I told you to focus on _one_ of your four requirements so that the post follows the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask), but I can see how you may have read it as being told to remove everything. The best way I know of to debug "what a silent PS script is doing" is to `alert` important information. So for this code I'd start with `alert("replaceAllSmartObjectContents: " + currentLayer.typename + ", " + currentLayer.kind)` at the start of the `replaceAllSmartObjectContents` function, so that you can see what values you get and why neither your `if` nor `else if` kick in.

Comment: (you're actually very close to working code, much closer than you probably think, but you do need to run that alert in part because it'll help you with any future problems while scripting for PS, and in part because it's important that _you_ discover what's wrong, since it's an easy to miss, but also basic programming mistake)

Comment: I wrote you an answer, but really you should have discovered this all on your own. Debugging is important, even if that means sticking a bunch of `alert`s in to figure out what's going on. Understand the code you're working with. And if there's no tooling to do that, use whatever method gains you insight into values that you have available.

Comment: Strange. You told me to try some alerts and told me how, then proceed to post an answer, but tell me I should have really figured it out for myself, without even giving me a chance to try? OK.

Comment: Yes, because you stopped responding, and I had to go to bed, so I assumed you walked away from your post (which is what usually happens when someone's engaged in a comment thread and then suddenly stops commenting. Typically, they never come back). I was going to post the answer after you discovered the problem yourself, but you disappeared, so I posted the answer when my day ended so that future visitors would have an answer to look at.

Comment: I stopped replying because I was trying to figure this out. Given this isn't a chat room there was nothing more to say until I was done. Which I still am not.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to debug a PS script is to `alert` values to see what's happening at each stage. If we add the following to the start of the `replaceAllSmartObjectContents` function:

```js
alert("replaceAllSmartObjectContents: " + currentLayer.typename + ", " + currentLayer.kind)
```

Then running the script shows us that the `typename` is `Document`, and that the `kind` is `undefined`, neither of which make sense if we're working with a layer. Looking at the code, we see that your `replaceAllSmartObjectContents` function has the following signature:

```js
function replaceAllSmartObjectContents(currentLayer) {
  ...
}
```

so your function is expecting a layer, no problems there. However, when we look at where you're calling it, we see:

```js
if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
    var theName = myDocument.name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
    var thePath = myDocument.path;

    // Call the function to start the replacement process
    replaceAllSmartObjectContents(myDocument);
}
```

We can see that instead of a layer, you're passing it a document. Obviously, this isn't going to work, but we can fix that with a simple change:

```js
if (app.documents.length > 0) {
    var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
    var theName = myDocument.name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
    var thePath = myDocument.path;

    // Call the function to start the replacement process
    replaceAllSmartObjectContents(myDocument.activeLayer);
}
```

Now the script works fine, and will trigger image replacement (provided we have a layer with the appropriate name and smart object content, of course).

And if you want to run through all layers, rather than just the active layer, then you'd loop through `myDocument.layers` and run `replaceAllSmartObjectContents` for each layer in that collection.

(Also: you almost *certainly* want to change this code so that it doesn't only work when the document has a filename. Because having a filename or not is pretty much irrelevant to content replacement)

Comment: This only repairs the code to it's original functionality, before I amended it in an attempt to include nested smart objects.

Comment: It fixes the code _you're showing_ from "seemingly doing nothing" to being working code. Because it didn't "do nothing", it ran itself, was given a document instead of a layer, neither the `if` nor `else if` fired because their conditions weren't met, and `replaceAllSmartObjectContents` returned without calling anything else. With the core functionality restored, _you_ now get to focus on figuring out nested smart objects again (including using alerts to figure out what data is getting passed around) and if you get stuck on that, that's a _new_ question, as a new post.

Comment: (annoying as that sounds, SO has always had the rule that one post is for one question, so since you got stuck on a something simple but you weren't aware of how to debug, that's what my focus was on. Now that you _do_ know how to debug, this answer shows what was wrong in the code you showed, so _you_ can get back to trying to write the code you wanted and use the tools you now have to figure out what your code is or isn't doing, letting you fix problems that you couldn't even find before. And if you get stuck again, now even _with_ debugging, that's new a new post with far more, new details)

Comment: I updated the post with a small note on how to run through all layers instead of just the active layer, but that's again basic programming: you just look up [where to access the list of layers](https://theiviaxx.github.io/photoshop-docs/Photoshop/Document.html) in the document, and then work with that.

Comment: The question was for assistance on how to achieve replacing the contents of nested smart objects, not on how to revert it to the unbroken code I previously had. I see you eventually untwisted yourself slightly to provide 'some' sort of point in the right direction.

Comment: Your question was for four things, you rewrote it to what it is now, where the _main_ question is about the script not working, so we're addressing that here. Again: annoying and stupid as it may sound, one post is for _one question_ and it doesn't matter what was in your post before: your post is hung up on the script not working _at all_, and so that's you will be getting answers for. You now have more tools available to do the rest of the work _yourself_, and debug it when you get stuck, and if you get stuck even _with_ your newfound debugging powers, that's a new post. That's how SO works.

Comment: Read the final sentence of my question "How could it be achieved to include nested smart objects?"

Comment: Yep, and that's literally a reason to get your post closed: that's a second question well beyond the initial scope of "my script doesn't even do anything", and is a reason for people to vote questions closed as ["needs more focus"](). So instead of voting to close it, I've answered the _main_ problem in your post, and given you new tools with which you can now _renew_ your attempt at implementing the functionality you need in a way you were unable to before.

Comment: The code was broken ONLY because I attempted to include nested smart objects and as it is a requirement to show what you have tried...I did. THAT in of itself was not my question. Not "How do I fix the broken code?" but "Oops I broke it by trying to include nested objects. How can I make it work while also including nested objects?". Seriously! I won't respond any further.

Comment: That's your choice, but then you _really_ need to carefully reread the official ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) article, including the official article on how to prepare your [mcve] because posts only get answers based on how you've described the problem. No matter how I read _this_ post, it's hung up on not running at all. So start a new post, and focus on the part you had problems with by showing the working code you started with, showing the code you wrote based on that, talking about _why_ you wrote that code, what you're seeing it do, and what you already did as debugging